# External Solid State Hard Disk is not recognized in a time

Tags: hard-drive

My problem iS:

I have Ubuntu 15.04, when I connect an hdd (solid state) it is recognized, but only for a time, 1hr, etc, but after a time then is not more recognized, it is hide from my pc, and it cant be find into disk aplication, i need to restart for use again my external hard disk.

Comment: Well this might not be the cause but could it be that you have some power issues and your drive does not get enough power? You could try to use an external power supply or a usb hub... Another reason I could think of is power management that turns off your drive.

Comment: yea, i was trying with other disc and other cases, and it is ok u.u thnx for ur time!